# Why Android Studio button displaying image as expected but on real device showing some other image?

Tags: android

I am using Android Studio version 2.2. I am facing strange thing first time. In one of my layouts I am using image ‘abc.png’ and Android Studio preview showing the right preview with right image, but on real device the image is different. The real device getting image wrong constantly. I don’ know what am I doing wrong? Below is the button code.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_pay"
    android:textColor="#525252"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_normal"
    android:text="Pay" />
```

Android studio is showing this preview as expected because 'Button image' (text 'Pay' is placed) I am using is what it should be.

[image]

but on real device it is showing different image as shown below

[image]

The button is getting wrong image on real device. One more thing I have checked some this button with other colored images as background it is properly reflected on android studio preview but on real device it always shows the same image no matter what image I use on background. Any help?

Comment: firslt delete the app on your device and run it again. secondly ensure you dont have multiple assets for different screen sizes.

Comment: What I have already tried
1) I have delete app and installed it again 
2) Closed android studio and restarted again
3) I have changed the real device. Firstly I was using Motorolla and the used samsung
4) I am not using multiple resources. I mean I am only target cell phone not tablets

Comment: check and ensure in all your drawable folders so not a different image asset is provided for any other screen size or anything. make sure all assets with this name is the same.

Comment: I checked it again.I have only one drawable folder so there is no case of multiple resource I guess :(

Comment: is btn_normal a png or xml?

Comment: and it looks like the xml file you uploaded is not of the button. you have mentioned button size as 150X150dp, but the image is like 150X50dp

Comment: btn_normal is a png file and on preview of android studio it is showing right png but on real device it is loading xml file from drawable. I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

After struggling a lot, I have found the problem. The problem was not with Button png or xml drawable. The problem was in java coding. The image was placed programmatically. I have posted the answer in case it may help full for others.